# component not loading angular 2 rc5

Tags: angular, typescript

I am having problem with webpack prod build, components are not loading. And there is no error. But its weird that dev build is working fine..

Below is code snapshot

## freight-list.component.ts

```
@Component({
    selector: 'freightList',
    template: require('./freight-list.component.html')
})
```

Freight-list.component.html is using ***file-upload*** which is not getting loaded.

## freight-list.component.html

```
   <div [collapse]="hideFileUpload" class="card card-block card-header">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
         <div class="panel-body">
            <file-upload> </file-upload>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <br>
   <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading" style="height:800px; overflow-y: scroll;">
         <div class="panel-body">
            <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover table-condensed">
               <thead>
                  <tr>
                     <th>Section </th>
                     <th>Category</th>
                     <th>Product</th>
                     <th>Markup %</th>
                     <th>Effective Date</th>
                  </tr>
               </thead>
............
............
............
```

Below is code for ***file-upload*** directive

## freight-fileupload.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FileUploader } from 'ng2-file-upload/ng2-file-upload';

const URL = 'app/freight/upload';

@Component({
    selector: 'file-upload',
    template: require('./freight-fileupload.component.html')
})

export class FreightFileUploadComponent {
...
}
```

## app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    routing,
    HttpModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    ErrorComponent,
    FreightFileUploadComponent,
    FILE_UPLOAD_DIRECTIVES,
    CollapseDirective,
    FreightListComponent,
    FreightInputComponent,
    FreightPipe,
    TYPEAHEAD_DIRECTIVES,
    AppComponent
  ],
  exports:[FreightFileUploadComponent],
  providers: [
    FreightService,
    ProductMasterSearchService
  ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule {

}
```

Could anyone help, is anything wrong here?

Comment: If it’s working in the dev environment, chances are high that it’s not an issue with your application code. It’s likely a problem with your build.

Comment: Any hint what to check in production build??

Comment: No idea, depends a lot on how you build your stuff. If there are really no errors at all (build time or run time), I would check the build output if it actually included the newer code (maybe it’s old code).

Answer (score 0):

I think your @component decorator should look like this:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'freightList',
    templateUrl: 'some_folder/freight-list.component.html'
})
```

Notice templateUrl instead template
and 'some_folder' instead '.'

Comment: Hi Darko, freight-list.component.html is getting loaded properly, its the <file-upload> directive which is not working

Comment: I see now...did you try to move FILE_UPLOAD_DIRECTIVES from "declaration" section to "imports" sections? I have no idea....

Answer (score 0):

This was bug in angular rc5 and got fixed when i upgrated to rc6